# Populate 3 Dynamic Dropdowns

Tags: javascript, html, onchange

I have 3 dynamic dropdowns, which are all being populated from the preceding dropdown. My problem is when I programme my third dropdown, it interferes with my second so only my first dropdown works. It's probably quite simple but my programming skills are very limited.

Here's my code:

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
function populate(s1,s2){
 var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
 var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
 s2.innerHTML = "";
 if(s1.value == "Product1"){
  var optionArray = ["|","50|50","80|80","100|100","120|120","150|150","200|200","250|250","300|300"];
 } else if(s1.value == "Product2"){
  var optionArray = ["|","50|50","80|80","100|100","120|120","150|150","200|200"];
 } else if(s1.value == "Product3"){
  var optionArray = ["|","50|50","80|80","100|100","120|120","150|150","200|200","250|250","300|300"];
 } else if(s1.value == "Product4"){
  var optionArray = ["|","50|50","80|80","100|100","120|120","150|150","200|200"];
 }
 for(var option in optionArray){
  var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
  var newOption = document.createElement("option");
  newOption.value = pair[0];
  newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
  s2.options.add(newOption);
 }
}
function populate(s1,s2,s3){
 var s1 = document.getElementById(s1);
 var s2 = document.getElementById(s2);
 var s3 = document.getElementById(s3);
 s3.innerHTML = "";
 if(s1.value == ("Product1") &s2.value == ("50")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","100|100","120|120","150|150","200|200","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product1") &s2.value ==("80")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","100|100","120|120","150|150","200|200","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product1") &s2.value ==("100")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","100|100","120|120","150|150","200|200","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product1") &s2.value ==("120")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","120|120","150|150","200|200","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product1") &s2.value ==("150")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","150|150","200|200","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product1") &s2.value ==("200")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","200|200","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product1") &s2.value ==("250")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product1") &s2.value ==("300")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product2") &s2.value ==("50")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","100|100","120|120","150|150","200|200","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product2") &s2.value ==("80")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","100|100","120|120","150|150","200|200","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product2") &s2.value ==("100")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","150|150","200|200","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product2") &s2.value ==("120")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","200|200","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product2") &s2.value ==("150")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product2") &s2.value ==("200")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product3") &s2.value ==("50")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","150|150","200|200","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product3") &s2.value ==("80")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","150|150","200|200","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product3") &s2.value ==("100")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","150|150","200|200","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product3") &s2.value ==("120")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","150|150","200|200","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product3") &s2.value ==("150")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","150|150","200|200","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product3") &s2.value ==("200")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","150|150","200|200","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product3") &s2.value ==("200")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","200|200","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product3") &s2.value ==("250")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product3") &s2.value ==("250")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product3") &s2.value ==("300")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product4") &s2.value ==("50")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","150|150","200|200","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product4") &s2.value ==("580")) {

  var optionArray = ["|","200|200","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product4") &s2.value ==("100")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","250|250","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product4") &s2.value ==("120")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","300|300","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product4") &s2.value ==("150")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","350|350","400|400","450|450"];
 } else if(s1.value == ("Product4") &s2.value ==("200")) {
  var optionArray = ["|","450|450"];
 }
 for(var option in optionArray){
 var pair = optionArray[option].split("|");
 var newOption = document.createElement("option");
 newOption.value = pair[0];
 newOption.innerHTML = pair[1];
 s3.options.add(newOption);
 }
}
</script>
```

```html
<body>
<h2>Choose Your Product</h2>
<hr />
Choose Product:
<select id="slct1" name="slct1" onchange="populate(this.id,'slct2')">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="Product1">Product1</option>
  <option value="Product2">Product2</option>
  <option value="Product3">Product3</option>
  <option value="Product4">Product4</option>
</select>
<hr />
Choose Depth:
<select id="slct2" name="slct2" onchange="populate('slct2' 'slct1','slct3')"></select>
<hr />
Choose Height:
<select id="slct3" name="slct3"></select>
<hr />
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two major syntax errors:

1- You have two function with the same name! populate.

2- The call of the function's parameters in the second list is wrong `populate('slct2' 'slct1','slct3')"` there should be a `,` between slct2 and slct1.

Checkout this DEMO: http://jsbin.com/xameye/1/

Comment: @Jack You should familiarize yourself with using your browser's developer's tools and looking for Console tab. It show you valuable information about errors.

Answer (score 0):

there are few syntax errors in your code, and also you are using so many static values to populate the dropdown options, can you please correct the syntax errors and simplify the code, after that you will be able to see either proper result or an exact error.